# Peruvian insect identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

The above is an insect I found while visiting Peru. I’m no biology expert, and I was just curious to know what species of insect this was. I found it on a rock while exploring the ruins near Pisac, if that helps.

[image: weird bug]

Comment: Looks like a Megaloptera juvenile.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not *Megaloptera*. Looks like a lampyrid (firefly) larval or female form. Note especially what look like single tarsal claws (on the end of the feet). This is diagnostic for *Lampyridae (Coleoptera)*.